# Difference in Holding 6 holes and 7 holes in Indian Bamboo Flute

Tags: beginner, flute

Please clear my following doubts.

- What is the difference between 6 holes and 7 holes holding position in flutes ?
- Can I play a song with 6 holes in 8 hole flute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never played this instrument before, but I can play most of the woodwinds, including flute, recorder, and tin whistle.  I did a quick search, and if I'm understanding this thing correctly, it's fundamentally very similar to the fife and uses the same fingerings as the fife and tin whistle.

A 7-hole instrument is extended downwards one extra step.  The first 6 holes function exactly the same as on the 6-hole variety, but covering the additional hole achieves an extra low note.  So music written for a 6-hole instrument is always playable on a 7-hole instrument, but music written for a 7-hole instrument (that uses that lowest note) wouldn't be entirely playable on a 6-hole instrument without transposing the music.

Comment: But I could see people holding 7 holes in 8 hole flute. Does that 8th hole even matters ?

Answer (score 0):

Indian Music consist of 2 types
1) Carnatic Music
2) North Indian or Hindustani classical music.

Carnatic Musicians uses 7 playing Holes Bamboo flute.
Where as there are only 6 playing holes in Hindustani classical based flute.

The difference is done to produce different notes which are differently produced.